# Sql Server, Composite Primary keys and clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, composite-key, clustered-index

How does Sql Server handle fill factor on tables with clustered indexes on composite primary keys?

I would assume a key node value would be generated based on the fields that make up the clustered index.  Would this mean that each new row inserted would effectively get inserted to at the end of the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would this mean that each new row
>   inserted would effectively get
>   inserted to at the end of the index?

No, it would be inserted where it belongs in the order of the columns that make up the index. In other words if you PK is zipcode and state (silly example) and you insert 22222, NJ then it will be inserted after 22222, NI and before 22222,NK